# Array of custom Structs MASM Windows API

Tags: assembly, struct, x86, masm, masm32

This is something I’ve been trying to figure out.  I want to make a MASM program that has a custom struct and an array of those structs and then saves it to a file.  I can not find any good information on how this should/could be done.  I think resb semi-instruction might be helpful.  Anyway, this is what I have worked out so far, but obliviously having trouble.  Basically long term I want to make a simple DB-like MASM program, but that is a ways off, still in the learning stages.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include windows.inc
include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc

.data?
MyStruct STRUCT
    string db 4 dup(0)
    dw1 DWORD ?
    dw2 DWORD ?
    dw3 DWORD ?
MyStruct ENDS

;MyArray MyStruct 20 dup(?)
MyArray resb 10*sizeof MyStruct  ; not sure of how to go about creating an array of structs

.data
    fileName db "myfile.dat"
    properNouns db "John", "Mike", "Emily", "Mary", "David",0
    
.code
        
    ; open the file for writing
    invoke CreateFile,fileName,GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL
    mov handle,eax

    ; write the array to the file
    invoke WriteFile,handle,MyArray,sizeof MyArray,written,NULL

    ; close the file
    invoke CloseHandle,handle
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to change `dup(0)` to uninitialized `dup(?)` in `MyStruct`. It should look like this:

```
.data?
MyStruct STRUCT
    string db 4 dup(?)
    dw1 DWORD ?
    dw2 DWORD ?
    dw3 DWORD ?
MyStruct ENDS
```

In your uninitialized `.data?` segment you can then use:

```
MyArray MyStruct 20 dup (<>)
```

This should create space for an array of 20 `MyStruct` structures.

---

### Notes

- `resb` doesn't work as that is a [NASM](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.16.01/html/nasmdoc0.html) directive, not a MASM directive.
- The `.data?` (BSS) segment in a Windows PE executable will be zeroed out by the Windows program loader.
- In DOS the `.Data?` (BSS) segment would have to be set to zero by the programmer after the program is started. If you didn't zero out the `.data?` memory then it was possible for uninitialized data to contain garbage that may or may not contain zeroes.

Comment: That is a super cool answer because it worked, my program has other problems, but that is no longer one of them.  What does dup (<>) mean?  Is it just for arrays of structs? I knew that dup (?) means uninitialized.  I been doing a little better in asm lately, but when something goes bad it can be hard.  Thanks a whole lot.

Comment: @ChadBotting : `<>` when used in initialization is used to denote the collection of all the members in a structure. If you create a structure in the `.data` section rather than `.data?` you can create variables like `MyArray MyStruct <"He", 1, 2, 3>, <"taxi", 4, 5, 6>, 18 dup (<{0,0,0,0}, 0, 0, 0>)` . `{}` are used for arrays ie (`db 4 dup(?)` is a byte array and can be initialized as such.